# In terraform, How to use list of list of map?

Tags: terraform

I would like to use list of list of map in terraform.
I have 3 environements, multiple subnets for each.

```
segmented_subnets = {
  rest = {
    dev = [
      "subnet-", #a
      "subnet-", #b
    ]
    qa = [
      "subnet-"
      "subnet-"
    ]
  }
  dashboard = {
    dev = [
      "subnet-",
      "subnet-",
    ]
    qa = [
      "subnet-"
      "subnet-"
    ]
  }
  login = {
    dev = [
      "subnet-",
      "subnet-",
    ]
    qa = [
      "subnet-"
      "subnet-"
    ]
  }

}
```

I want to a access on these subnets, 
I tried :

```
"${element(var.segmented_subnets.rest.["${terraform.workspace}"], count.index)}"
```

or:

```
"$${element(var.segmented_subnets.rest.["${terraform.workspace}"], count.index)}"
```

can't manage to access to this variable

Comment: Maps of maps are a real pain in Terraform but there might be a much better way to do what you want using the `aws_subnet_ids` data source instead. If you have control over your subnets and their tags this would possibly be a better approach.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's worked much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with data use:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "foo" {
  vpc_id = "${var.vpcs["${terraform.workspace}"]}"

  tags {
    Name = "bar*"
  }
}
```

used by:

```
    resource "aws_instance" "ec2-foo" {
...
      instance_type        = "t2.small"
      subnet_id            = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.foo.ids[count.index]}"
...
```